# javascript operator "in"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm used to python, so

```
a = [1,2,3]
1 in a # -> True
b = ["1", "2", "3", "x"]
"x" in b # -> True
```

Why is it that in JavaScript

```
a = [1,2,3]
1 in a // -> true
b = ["1", "2", "3", "x"]
"x" in b // -> false
```

and much weirder

```
"1" in b // -> true
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` works on KEYS of arrays, not values. `1 in a` succeeds because there is an element #1 in your array, which is actually the `2` value.

`"1"` fails, because there is no `1` **PROPERTY** or **KEY** in your array.

Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: There's [array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), but it's a newer JS feature and won't be in older implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you have to understand about JavaScript is almost everything is an "Object" that can have properties. Array's are just a special type of object whose properties are integer indexes and have push, pop, shift, unshift, etc. methods. Plus they can be defined with the square bracket shorthand you used:

```
a = [1,2,3];
```

This creates an Array object with the properties:

```
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
```

Now as others have said, all the `in` operator does is check that an object has a property of that name and `a[1] == 2` therefore `1 in a == true`. On the other hand,

```
b = ["1", "2", "3", "x"];
```

created an Array object with the properties:

```
b[0] = "1";
b[1] = "2";
b[2] = "3";
b[3] = "x";
```

So `b["x"] == undefined` therefore `"x" in b == false`.

The other thing you have to understand is JavaScript uses "duck typing", meaning if it looks like a number, JavaScript treats it like a number. In this case, `b["1"] == 2` therefore `"1" in b == true`. I'm not 100% certain whether this is duck typing at work or JavaScript just always treats property names as Strings.

If you wanted to declare a generic object that wouldn't have the Array methods but had the same properties you would write:

```
var b = {"0": "1", "1": "2", "2": "3", "3": "x"};
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
var b = {}; // This declares an Object
b[0] = "1";
b[1] = "2";
b[2] = "3";
b[3] = "x";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `"x" in b` is looking for a property name `'x'`. There is none, they are all numerical (but still string)  property names, considering it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

`1` is a valid vanilla numeric array index, `x` is not; `in` works with array indexes/object member names, not their values.

Answer (score 0):

"1" is not a property of the array object...