# Why does ("a" in ["a","b"]) yield false, and (1 in [1,2]) yield true?

Tags: javascript, match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript in operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635914/javascript-in-operator)

Why does `("a" in ["a","b"])` yield `false`, and `(1 in [1,2])` yield `true` ?
Is there a reason why `"a"` does not match the first element of that array and 1 does ?
Why won't it work with strings ?

Comment: Try `(10 in [10,20])` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) checks for the existence of properties by key, not by value. And your array of length 2 *has an index `"1"`* - `arr["1"]` is the value `2`. For example, also `0 in ["a", "b"]` is `true`. The behaviour does not depend on a string or a number being used.

You usually would use it on plain objects, not on arrays. Like `"a" in {a:1} === true`, or `"b" in {a:1} === false`.